# How can I find Amazon's S3 url Relative to the Server?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, relative-path

I signed up for Amazons S3 service.

I am having a problem with my Gallery script. It want the URL relative to the server where the files are located at?

So instead of `http://gallery.s3.amazonaws.com/10/images`

They want: `/home/www/gallery.s3.amazonaws.com/10/images`

The problem is I don't know what to use when it is Amazon s3?

Anybody have a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to specify what gallery software you are using.  (Gallery 2, Gallery 3, Coppermine, Etc.)  Or, are you writing your own script? If so, what language/platform?

Often, something expecting a physical path does not accept an HTTP URL unless HTTP support has been purposefully added.

Comment: using stadtaus php gallery script.

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that, or delete and create a new question. Regardless, I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. The PHP script expects to work on files in a local directory. It probably does not have support for loading and/or saving images over HTTP.